# Laravel query Builder with DATE mysql function

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

Hi I have a query in my laravel project which should retrieve dates between ranges. My query is:

```
 $dateFrom = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($request->dateFrom));
      $dateTo = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($request->dateTo));
      $posts = DB::table('posts')->join('categories','posts.category_id','=','categories.id')->
                join('users','posts.user_id','=','users.id')
                ->select('posts.id','posts.topic','categories.category_name','posts.created_at','users.name')
                ->whereBetween('posts.created_at',[$dateFrom,$dateTo])
                ->get();
```

I'd like to use DATE mysql_function on column `posts.created_at` but I don't know how could I do it. Below query dosen't work:

```
$dateFrom = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($request->dateFrom));
      $dateTo = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($request->dateTo));
       $posts = DB::table('posts')->join('categories','posts.category_id','=','categories.id')->
                join('users','posts.user_id','=','users.id')
                ->select('posts.id','posts.topic','categories.category_name','posts.created_at','users.name')
                ->whereBetween('DATE(posts.created_at)',[$dateFrom,$dateTo])
                ->get();
```

I would be greatful for help. Best regards ;)

Comment: why don't you use two [`whereDate`](https://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_whereDate) instead..? something like `->whereDate('posts.created_at', '>=', $dateFrom)->whereDate('posts.created_at', '<=', $dateTo)`. i know its somewhat too verbose, but then.. the easiest way..

Answer (score 1):

change  `->whereBetween('DATE(posts.created_at)'`

to      `->whereBetween(DB::raw('DATE(posts.created_at)'))`

if you want to add some raw expression in a query you can use `DB::row` method as mentioned in [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#raw-expressions)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Carbon` like this:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
...

$dateFrom = Carbon::parse($request->dateFrom);
$dateTo = Carbon::parse($request->dateTo);
$posts = DB::table('posts')
    ->join('categories','posts.category_id','=','categories.id')
    ->join('users','posts.user_id','=','users.id')
    ->select('posts.id','posts.topic','categories.category_name','posts.created_at','users.name')
    ->whereBetween('posts.created_at',[$dateFrom,$dateTo])
    ->get();
```